# Post request error 400 when trying to search a website

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to search for movie titles here: https://classindportal.mj.gov.br/consulta-filmes and scrape the resulting page. I know this involves an intermediary step of sending a certain request to the site with my search term, which I currently cannot get to work.

When using Google DevTools, the network tab shows me the following info

```
Request URL: https://classindportal.mj.gov.br/api/solicitacao-classificacao-consultas/list
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

and that the request payload contains a key `tituloBr`, which will have a value equal to the search term (e.g. `{'tituloBr': 'shrek'}` if I type 'shrek' in the search bar and press enter).

I believe the search involves sending a post request to the Request URL as shown above, sending the data `{'tituloBr': 'shrek'}` so I used the requests library as follows:

```
payload = {'tituloBr': 'shrek'}
r = requests.post('https://classindportal.mj.gov.br/api/solicitacao-classificacao-consultas/list', data = payload)
```

but this gives an error code 400 with `r.reason` showing `'Bad Request'`.

I don't think there is any problem with the URL or data I have sent, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Check dev tools again. That post request has much more parameters

Comment: It is possible that it has to do with the headers for the request, have you looked into the api documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iv'e inspected the page, and seems like you need to provide a `token` - which can be obtained by sending a `POST` request to:

```
https://sso.mj.gov.br/auth/realms/PRD/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

So, get the token, and then send *another*  request to the API with the token to search for your desired movie

```py
import requests


SEARCH_TERM = "shrek"

token_url = "https://sso.mj.gov.br/auth/realms/PRD/protocol/openid-connect/token"
movies_url = (
    "https://classindportal.mj.gov.br/api/solicitacao-classificacao-consultas/list"
)


headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8",
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJMRVNSQzZ4UGtUdnlzNUdvUHpwaHNmeTJTSmMta0ZZcjFKM2VBNS1uOExnIn0.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.RbreSBJYQ4aPZYEQmSHWo5ZkQaEEy4M9UqWkOHg2wRAoQsxHCzo3dj3CRilyHocnt-K6toV1MUVF_pk1rg2IYeOcrq5NJFaErKGl4Iy69dG_PBwU1RHP3da5-paLDg6DPZZTu2UR1FmShuvlzaSXFNe5JSDoWP1RMjpCSP5bBpXHz0M-KvbZqPykYky-pIpxCpwEIlsL15hpTFqxrghpvWcpiLfjC-YRALynXxPZFiDzqpNq9nsQwLFCXjC6lAeZmP3GQcDZMIDEBgeSx7slomM2E360teqK2WXmZHmJxRwIWP1snJDetlxbDlDHuFxGVLyLsR8kJMbKTPnZEeDUyw",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Origin": "https://classindportal.mj.gov.br",
    "Referer": "https://classindportal.mj.gov.br/consulta-filmes",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
}


json_data = {
    "currentPage": 0,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "sortItem": None,
    "totalResults": None,
    "itens": None,
    "tituloBr": f"{SEARCH_TERM}",
    "tituloOr": "",
    "requerente": "",
    "produtor": "",
    "editora": "",
    "idModulo": 1,
}


token_data = {
    "client_id": "classind-consultapublica-frontend",
    "client_secret": "4PmaBa8bBeVow40SKFNb7qNHzAxuLoqz",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "classind-backend",
}


with requests.Session() as session:
    token = session.post(token_url, data=token_data).json()["access_token"]
    headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token}"
    response = session.post(movies_url, json=json_data, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())
```

---

You can even convert the data to a Pandas data frame if you'd like:

```py
import pandas as pd
# ...

with requests.Session() as session:
    token = session.post(token_url, data=token_data).json()["access_token"]
    headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token}"
    response = session.post(movies_url, json=json_data, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()["itens"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
       id       tituloBrasil  ... classificacaoAtribuida classificacaoPretendida
0  164346              SHREK  ...                  Livre                    None
1  164345            SHREK 2  ...                  Livre                    None
2  164344  SHREK PARA SEMPRE  ...                  Livre                    None
3  164343     SHREK TERCEIRO  ...                  Livre                    None
4  146845            SHREK 2  ...                  Livre                    None
5  146844     SHREK TERCEIRO  ...                  Livre                    None
6  135770              SHREK  ...                  Livre                    None
7  135769            SHREK 2  ...                  Livre                    None
8  135768  SHREK PARA SEMPRE  ...                  Livre                    None
9  135767     SHREK TERCEIRO  ...                  Livre                    None

[10 rows x 8 columns]
```

---

It does seem like there is some pagination to do - but I'll leave that upto the OP.